# How to fix Carbon timezone after upgrading to Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon, laravel-5.8

After upgrading to Laravel 5.8 the "created_at" field is returning a string like this

> "createdAt": "2019-05-01T16:36:25.000000Z"

But I want to return an object like before in Laravel 5.7
like this:

> "createdAt": {
>               "date": "2019-05-01 19:36:25.000000",
>               "timezone_type": 3,
>               "timezone": "Asia/Baghdad"
>           }

I did look around the web found nothing about it and there's nothing about it too in upgrade guide too.
I'm returning it from resources just like that a JSON:

```php
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'createdAt' => $this->created_at,
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how I could solve it:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'createdAt' => $this->created_at,
        'date' => Carbon::serializeUsing(function ($createdAt) {
          return [
              'date' => $createdAt->toDateTimeString(),
              'timezone_type' => $createdAt->timezone_type,
              'timezone' => $createdAt->tzName,
          ];
        }),
   ];
}
```

Now it returns an object like this:

```
"createdAt": {
     "date": "2019-05-01 19:36:25",
     "timezone_type": 3,
     "timezone": "Asia/Baghdad"
},
"date": null
```

The breaking change is documented in the [official Carbon documentation](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-carbon-2).

Answer (score 0):

Try returning a carbon instance of the date:

```
Carbon::parse($this->created_at)
```

Comment: returns the string too "createdAt": "2019-05-01T16:36:25.000000Z"